# Confirming type of object in IEnumerable<Interface1> also implements Interface2

Tags: c#, interface, casting, resharper

I have one interface, `ICoordinate` and two types that implement it. I have a collection of `IEnumerable<ICoordinate>`. One of the types that implements `ICoordinate` also implements the interface `IExpirable`.

## Object One

- `ICoordinate`
- `IExpirable`

## Object Two

- `ICoordinate`

The `IEnumerable<ICoordinate>` is composed of many of each type of object. I would like to be able to determine if each object implements `IExpirable`, as I already know that both objects implement `ICoordinate`. I have tried checking using:

```
var coordObj = coord as IExpirable
```

and

```
if(coord is IExpirable)
```

Both of these examples make resharper complain about `suspicious comparisons or and suspicious casts`. Specifically, they say `there is no type in the solution which is inherited from both type A and type B`.

Comment: What about casting the object to its underlying type and then testing if it implements IExpirable?  That's obviously an ugly way to handle interfaces, but maybe that will address the resharper complaint?

Comment: Seems like that ought to work, can you post more of your code so we can see the full context?

Comment: What yoyo said. A minimal repro gives no complaint from R# when I try it. Please provide the smallest code that gives the problem. Just one little thing: When you say ". I have a collection of `IEnumerable<ICoordinate>`", you mean you have *many* `IEnumerable<ICoordinate>`s or *a single* `IEnumerable<ICoordinate>` (which is of course a collection) ? If the former, then yes there's no point trying to convert each `IEnumerable<ICoordinate>` in turn to `IExpirable`...

Answer (score 0):

I use `GetInterface` method.

```
AppSession.Current.ModulesConfiguration.Select(
                    module =>
                    {
                        var path = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(pathToAssemblies, module.ModuleRelativePathForDll),
                            module.BusinessModuleDllName);
                        return path;
                    })
                    .Select(Assembly.LoadFrom)
                    .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                    .FirstOrDefault(type => type.GetInterface(interfaceType.Name) != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through your collection and pick all which implements your second interface with Linq (or better its extension methods which I prefer over the true LINQ syntax):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

        IEnumerable<ICoordinate> list=...;
        foreach(IExpirable expirable in list.OfType<IExpirable>())
        {
            ...
        }
```